# RakNet crosscompile issue from x86/64 to ARM64 jetson nano missing <sys/io.h>

Tags: compiling, arm64

I try to crosscompile RakNet from Ubuntu x86/64 to Ubuntu ARMv8/64 jetson nano and when I run the makefile, it indicates, that the  is missing.

As far as I know  is not a part of ARMv8-64 Ubuntu, but somehow I have to build RakNet. Can anyone help me how I could solve this issue

Thank you for your help, Zoltan

Comment: Did you install the libc6-dev-amd64-cross package?

Comment: Hi,

Yes I did, the package has been installed without any issue, but the error message remained.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply comment out the use of io.h in FileList.cpp, its not actually used in the file when building ARM so it isn't missed.